# Angular2 - NgFor with SVG

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I have an a SVG Element that I would like to draw with ngFor. The SVG only consists of lines, so theoretically it should be possible.
I currently have the following code:

my-component.js:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'my-component.html'
})

export class MyComponent{
  lines: [
    { weight: 0.4, x1: 86.69, y1: 1, x2: 98.91, y2: 1 },
    { weight: 0.5, x1: 85.31, y1: 9.67, x2: 98.23, y2: 9.67 }
  ]
}
```

my-component-html:

```html
<svg id="lines" viewBox="0 0 320.6 542.59" *ngFor='line of lines'>
  <line class="line" [attr.x1]="{{ x1 }}" [attr.y1]="{{ y1 }}" [attr.x2]="{{ x2 }}" [attr.y2]="{{ y2 }}"/>
</svg>
```

It is not working and I am sure that I have multiple syntax mistakes, but I don't know which ones exactly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't mix binding and interpolation. Try this:

```
<svg id="lines" viewBox="0 0 320.6 542.59" >
  <line *ngFor="let line of lines" class="line" [attr.x1]="line.x1" [attr.y1]="line.y1" [attr.x2]="line.x2" [attr.y2]="line.y2"/>
</svg>
```

And also change `:` to `=` in your component

```
export class MyComponent{
  lines = [ // here
    { weight: 0.4, x1: 86.69, y1: 1, x2: 98.91, y2: 1 },
    { weight: 0.5, x1: 85.31, y1: 9.67, x2: 98.23, y2: 9.67 }
  ];
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! Will accept as soon as the 4 minutes are over.

Answer (score 2):

**JUST A SUGGESTION**

Another solution would be to use [ngx-svg module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-svg), which would allow to generate SVG objects easily. To reproduce the above code you would have to include the module and then in the view you could use -

```
<svg-container containerId="lineContainer">
  <svg-line *ngFor="let line of lines" [borderSize]="line.weight" [x0]="line.x1" [y0]="line.y1" [x1]="line.x2" [y2]="line.y2"></svg-line>
</svg-container>
```

Additionally to the above parameters you can also listen for multiple events, like onClick, onMouseOver, onMouseOut, onDoubleClick, and pass the border color variable.

Beside the line svg object, you can create also different objects (ellipse, rectangular, polyline, polygon and more) with this library.